# Equivalente a count con group by en MongoDB con array de datos

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Vengo de SQL no tengo mucha(nada prácticamente) experiencia en MongoDB.
Tengo la siguiente información en una colección(*ToDo*) en mongo:

```
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "example description",
            "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "lorem blablablab",
            "tags": ["tag1","tag2"],
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "lorem blablablab",
            "tags": ["tag2", "tag3"],
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "description": "lorem blablablab",
            "tags": ["tag2"],
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "description": "lorem blablablab",
            "tags": ["tag3"]
        }
```

viendo el dato *tags*, que contiene una lista con elementos de tipo string(tag1, tag2 y/o tag3), en SQL (y relacionándolo de forma correcta) se podría hacer un count(tags) con un group by para realizar el conteo de cada uno de esos valores, osea, cuantas tareas están asociadas a cada uno de los tags:

```
tag1 ---> 2
tag2 ---> 4
tag3 ---> 3
```

El conflicto esta en cómo replicar ese tipo de consulta en mongo.
Busco información para poder trabajar con las listas de tags sin tener que analizar del lado del cliente si los datos se repiten o no. la idea es optimizar la operación por medio de la consulta.
Se está utilizando python y pyMongo.

Mil gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te adjunto una posible solución:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags" // descompone el array en un documento por separado
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tags", // agrupamos por el tags
      count: {
       $sum: 1 // Realizamos sumatoria
      }
  }
}
])
```

Esta consulta te daria el siguiente resultado:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "tag1",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "tag2",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "tag3",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

No se esta salida te valdría, si lo necesitaras en un objeto se tendría que hacer un merge de los objetos.

Espero que esto te haya podido ayudar.

Un saludo

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, la salida es perfecta. Con ese resultado ya puedo recorrer la lista e imprimir los datos. También lo necesitaba ordenado, pero es cuestión de agregar un sort a la lista dentro del aggregate. Mil gracias por todo.